# How to capture databricks notebook failure to cluster timeout into DataFactory pipeline, passing the error through usp to azure sql db

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks

DataFactory connects to data bricks and calls a notebook. When the notebook completes it either

[image]

- Upon success > sends to pipeline log
- Upon failure > sends to the pipeline error log

This works fine and picks up errors if there is a problem with the data source.

However, when the notebook fails due to it losing connection to data bricks, by which I mean the database cluster loses connection.

[image]

Consequently, the data factory pipeline fails and does not pass this into the activity Stored Procedure: SP_Pipeline_Error_Log

- which is just a stored procedure that runs to update an error table with some parameters being passed through

Error from data bricks notebook:
“the spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. your notebook will be automatically reattached”

I can see that the data factory pipeline failure happens around the same time the cluster connection goes via the data bricks cluster log.

[image]

How can I capture the databricks connection failure into my SP_Pipeline_Error_Log?

How can I prevent this error from happening? I've read online it can be down to a memory issue caused by cache.

I can provide more detail if needed.

Comment: Can you share the complete error message that you see from Failed notebook activity

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

"Pipeline result is success if and only if all nodes evaluated succeed" Here are some know errors and their troubleshooting [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-troubleshoot-guide#azure-databricks)

You can checkout this [external document](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6712/azure-data-factory-pipeline-logging-error-details/) of a similar scenario and for alternative methods of capturing errors, read  [Get Any Azure Data Factory Pipeline Activity Error details with Azure Functions.](https://mrpaulandrew.com/2020/04/22/get-any-azure-data-factory-pipeline-activity-error-details-with-azure-functions/) and Share your feedback at official ADF forum [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)